# Duplicate data in pymongo with indexes

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a meto station and I query an API to have data.
I query this API every 15 minutes with crontab. The response is an XML file that I parse to extract data.
The station give data in this format:

```
<sensore id="2" nome="Temperatura Aria" unita="°C" tipo="6">
<misura timestamp="1630620300" data_ora="2021-09-03 00:05:00" valore="18.620"/>
<misura timestamp="1630621215" data_ora="2021-09-03 00:20:15" valore="18.850"/>
<misura timestamp="1630622130" data_ora="2021-09-03 00:35:30" valore="18.620"/>
<misura timestamp="1630623046" data_ora="2021-09-03 00:50:46" valore="18.550"/>
```

If I query the API at 2021-09-03 00:00:00 it gives the data acquired...If I query after 15 minutes the API gives the data just acquired plus the new data.
These data are stored in MongoDB in a collection.
I define in my python script 3 indexes to prevent duplicate data:

```
collection-create_index('unity', pymongo.ASCENDING, 'id_sensor', pymongo.ASCENDING,    'date_time', pymongo.ASCENDING)
```

but it seems it doesn't work correctly because sometimes there are duplicate data, for example:

```
6133b7a65a0291ae76667132, 1 Unita 1, 2, temperaturaAria, 2052, 1630778788, 04/09/2021, 20:06, 20040
6133bb2902794c201efa5852, 1 Unita 1, 2, temperaturaAria, 2052, 1630779703, 04/09/2021, 20:21, 19370
6133beadd3ad130f9273aa2f, 1 Unita 1, 2, temperaturaAria, 2052, 1630779703, 04/09/2021, 20:21, 19370
6133beadd3ad130f9273aa30, 1 Unita 1, 2, temperaturaAria, 2052, 1630780618, 04/09/2021, 20:36, 18950
6133c2317e5f2476eeb52747, 1 Unita 1, 2, temperaturaAria, 2052, 1630781629, 04/09/2021, 20:53, 18540
```

air temperature at 20:21 is duplicated...
Some hint to prevent really duplicates?

Comment: You can think about creating the index type as _unique_.

Comment: Create index doesn't create a unique indexes.. with option unique=True it seems to work fine.